# likelihood function of tobit model when y can only be 0 or 1

Tags: maximum-likelihood, tobit-regression

As you can see, [image], here is the likelihood function of tobit model when observed y equals 0 when it is smaller then $y_L$.

What is the form when observed y equals 0 when it is smaller then $y_L$, AND y equals 1 when it is not smaller then $y_L$?

Does the first term become $\Phi(\frac{X_j\beta-y_L}{\sigma})$ ?

Does this special case still called tobit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term would become the probability that $y_j \ge y_L$, so I think you are right.  This would be $\Phi \left(\frac{X_j \beta - y_L}{\sigma} \right)$.

I guess the case where the objective is truncated to both ends is equivalent to probit (I did not prove it formally. There could be some difference).